# Using "and" to combine two sentences

Tags: punctuation, writing, conjunctions

I would like to combine these two sentences.

> Have significant experience of managing office and warehouse.
>
> Have experience of managing people at office and warehouse.

Can I use *and* to do that?

> Significant experience of managing office and warehouse, **and** managing
>   people in them.

Comment: Will Hunting, trying to learn using one sentence in place of two. For example: 1. Have significant experience of managing office nad warehouse. I have experience of managing people at office and warehouse.

Please guide.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/and#Conjunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may rewrite the sentence as

> I have significant experience in managing offices, warehouses and the
>   people in them.